# link Change in core php

Tags: wordpress

I am use core php and i want to change url. This is my actual URL. http://www.example.com/blogs/blog_single.php?title=Need-of-a-Professional

and i want that type of url: http://www.example.com/blogs/Need-of-a-Professional

so what i do?

Please help me, How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.fusion-fullwidth').waypoint(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    odometer.innerHTML = 78;
  }, 1000);
});
```